# REST api - Update email and status subscriber into AllSubscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api

I am studing the api call to insert/update (upsert) one or more subscribers both in a dedicated data extension and AllSubscribers at the same time.

I found this api calls:
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createContacts.htm (for insert)
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/updateContacts.htm (for update)

I can insert or update records in both  structure but I can't update the status and email information on AllSubscribers.

Have you any idea? Exist other calls?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To access All Subscribers you need to use the SOAP API as described on the [API overview](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm) in the documentation.

- [Create a subscriber](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/create_a_subscriber.htm)
- [Update a subscriber](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/update_a_subscriber.htm)

Comment: Ok, but I also found that using the api call (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createContacts.htm) creates both a contact (into AllContacts) and a subscriber (into AllSubscribers).

I thought that maybe the call could also handle the status of a subscriber in the AllSubscribers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to update a large buch of subscribers, you can also post a csv file into your BU's FTP and import it into both 'AllSubscribers' and your DataExtension using a scheduled/file drop automation.

Comment: The number of records is variable and It is a real time integration.
Is it a best practice performe an automation for few records?


Updates could be done with a high frequency